# How to access curl data with oauth in web.py

Tags: python, curl, web.py

I have this code, it sends a request to my server which is run by `web.py`:

```
url = "https://sample.com/api"    
auth_string = 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ("usernamexxxx", "codexxxx"))[:-1]    
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "authorization": auth_string}    
data = {"message":"WELCOME!..."}    
req = urlfetch.fetch(url, method=urlfetch.POST, payload= simplejson.dumps(data), headers= headers)    
response = req.content
```

So when I receive this kind of request in my web server I want to check if the username and code input to the request is valid or not? And how can I access the given data of the code above?

Comment: if the username and password is invalid won't you get a 401 response back from the server? If so you can do it by sending the request and looking at the status code of the response. If its a 401 you know you performed an invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can access those headers via the `os.environ` dictionary.